# Jackson Dealing With Interfaces

Tags: java, json, interface, jackson

I am using `Jackson` to serialize/deserialize a payload that will be stored in a database. I am having some trouble figuring out how to deal with interfaces. I am trying to serialize the `Request` class below, but am getting errors saying that Jackson cannot serialize abstract classes. How can I go about serializing/deserializing this payload properly? If possible, I would like to avoid modifying the classes themselves. Thanks.

```
public interface myInterface {
    public Obj1 getObj1();
    public void setObj1(Obj1 Obj);
    public String getState();
    public void setState(String state);
} 

// Serializing this class
public class Request {
    private myInterface myInt;
    private String message;
    private String requestId;

    public Request(String message, myInterface int) {
        this.message = message;
        this.myInt = int;
    }

    public Request(String requestID, myInterface int) {
        this.requestId = requestID;
        this.myInt = int;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public VipNGEntity getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public void myInt(myInterface myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
}

public class Vip extends PersistentEntity implements myInterface {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: When using inheritance, you it is a bit more complicated. See this [blog](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) for examples how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not elegant, one solution is to specify the implementation class in the interface.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=MyImplClass.class)
public interface myInterface {
    public Obj1 getObj1();
    public void setObj1(Obj1 Obj);
    public String getState();
    public void setState(String state);
}
```

The drawback of this is that your interface becomes aware of the implementation.

A better option IMO is to use Jackson configuration, as explained here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: The last sentence is slightly misleading. One could assume that the Mixin approach makes the code dependent but actually its a neat way to separate jackson concerns from other stuff. Using a jackson-annotation like @JsonDeserialize on the other other hand directly introduces a dependency.

Comment: @DoeJohnson You are right - I have removed the misleading sentence.